# failed to find global token filter under [synonym]

Tags: search, curl, elasticsearch

So from the documentation on [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-analyze.html), seems like I can build a *custom transient analyzer out of tokenizers, token filters and char filters* and test it against my sample text using the Analyze API.

The goal is that I want to see if the [synonym token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html#analysis-synonym-tokenfilter) satisfies my needs in terms of which terms get labelled as synonyms and which do not.

But when I do

> curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?char_filters=html_strip&tokenizer=whitespace&token_filters=synonym' -d 'man and male are same'

Rather than getting a result, I get

```
{
  "error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to find global token filter under [synonym]]",
  "status": 400
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Has the synonym filter been configured? You need to configure one before using it

Comment: Crap! you're right it needs to be configured first. I thought its inbuilt. Thanks anywyas

Answer (score 2):

It is currently not possible to use an ad-hoc synonym token filter due to the implementation requiring access "to the tokenizer factories for the index." (See [elasticsearch Github issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23943).) Unfortunately this limitation is currently undocumented for the [docs on using custom token filters on the _analyze endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html)

Here are some example commands to create and update a synonym token filter using the method of re-opening the index:

```
# create index with filter
curl -v -X PUT -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'localhost:9200/syn_test_idx' -d '
{
  "settings" : {
    "analysis" : {
      "filter" : {
        "test_synonym_filter" : {
          "type" : "synonym",
          "synonyms" : [
            "i-pod, i pod => ipod",
            "universe, cosmos"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

# test token filter
' | jq .
curl -X POST -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'localhost:9200/syn_test_idx/_analyze' -d '{
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "filter": ["global_synonym_filter"],
  "text": "cow i phone"
}' | jq .
```

("i phone" not caught by synonym list.)

```
# update index
curl -X POST -s 'localhost:9200/syn_test_idx/_close' | jq .
curl -X PUT -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'localhost:9200/syn_test_idx/_settings' -d '{
  "analysis" : {
    "filter": {
      "test_synonym_filter":{
        "type":"synonym",
        "synonyms" : [
          "i-pod, i pod => ipod",
          "universe, cosmos",
          "i-phone, i phone => iphone"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}' | jq .
curl -X POST -s 'localhost:9200/syn_test_idx/_open' | jq .

# test token filter
' | jq .
curl -X POST -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'localhost:9200/syn_test_idx/_analyze' -d '{
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "filter": ["global_synonym_filter"],
  "text": "cow i phone"
}' | jq .
```

("i phone" translated into "iphone" by synonym list.)

(On an unrelated note, my zsh/YADR setup for some reason doesn't show post response bodies, hence I am piping it through `jq`.)